# How to render multiple rows for a a only a given column in react using react tables?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to display tabular data of the format,

```
[
      {
          "user1":{
              "firstName": ["abcd"],
              "lastName":[ "xyz"],
          },
          "user2": {
              "firstName": "qwer",
              "lastName": "nmas"
          },
          "others": [
              {
                  "firstName": "sadas",
                  "lastName": "sadas"
              },
              {
                  "firstName": "cccc",
                  "lastName": "nmcs"

              }
            ]
      }
  ]
```

I want to render this data using react rows. How do I render others which is an array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array is assigned to variable `data`:

```
data[0].others.map(item => <p>{`${item.firstname} ${item.lastName}`}</p>)
```

If your `data` array contains more than 1 item, you can map it too:

```
data.map(d => d.others.map(item => <p>{`${item.firstname} ${item.lastName}`}</p>))
```